# Linking library with a different symbol versions

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linker, shared-libraries

I'm trying to build a program. let's called it `exampleprog`.
This program depends on a library : `libdeezer`. And I've only access to the shared library (libdeezer.so).

Finally, `libdeezer` depends on several libraries including `libcurl`. My problem is that I can't build `exampleprog` because the linker don't find functions from `libcurl`. Here is `make` output :

```
gcc -o NanoPlayer main.o -L../libdeezer/SDK/Bins/Platforms/Linux/x86_64 -Wl,-rpath=../libdeezer/SDK/Bins/Platforms/Linux/x86_64 -ldeezer -lcurl
/usr/bin/ld: ../libdeezer/SDK/Bins/Platforms/Linux/x86_64/libdeezer.so: undefined reference to `curl_multi_assign@CURL_OPENSSL_3'
[...]
/usr/bin/ld: ../libdeezer/SDK/Bins/Platforms/Linux/x86_64/libdeezer.so: undefined reference to `curl_global_cleanup@CURL_OPENSSL_3'
/usr/bin/ld: ../libdeezer/SDK/Bins/Platforms/Linux/x86_64/libdeezer.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_recv@CURL_OPENSSL_3'
```

Also, here is the output of `ldd libdeezer.so`

```
./libdeezer.so: /lib64/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by ./libdeezer.so)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffde5920000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fba07993000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fba077b4000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007fba07706000)
    [...]
```

The `Makefile` I use

```
LIBDEEZER_DIR=../libdeezer/SDK
LIBDEEZER_INC_DIR=$(LIBDEEZER_DIR)/Include
LIBDEEZER_LIB_DIR=$(LIBDEEZER_DIR)/Bins/Platforms/Linux/x86_64

#Set tools and flags
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-W -Wall -I$(LIBDEEZER_INC_DIR) -Wno-unused-parameter
LDFLAGS=-L$(LIBDEEZER_LIB_DIR) -Wl,-rpath=$(LIBDEEZER_LIB_DIR) -ldeezer -lcurl
EXEC=NanoPlayer

all: $(EXEC)

NanoPlayer: main.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# Build every source files
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean mrproper

# Clean every temporary files
clean:
    rm -rf *.o

# Clean everything than can be generated
mrproper: clean
    rm -rf $(EXEC)
```

And libcurl symbol definition :

```
~ readelf -sW /lib64/libcurl.so.4.8.0 | grep -E "curl_multi_assign|memcmp"
    95: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND memcmp@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)
   508: 000000000004cfa0   108 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 curl_multi_assign
```

As you can see, the function `curl_multi_assign` does not have a symbol version but for instance `memcmp` have.

If I understood correctly,

- `@CURL_OPENSSL_3` after the function name the symbol version.
- I tried to change the soname of libcurl with patchelf program.
- I tried building an older version of libcurl with `--with-ssl` option

So my question is, could I either change symbol version in libcurl library or can tell the linker program to take unversioned symbols ?

Comment: Your `make` output does not match your `Makefile`. The `Makefile` shows `NanoPlayer` is built with the command `$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)`, and `LDFLAGS` ends with `-ldeezer -lcurl`, but the `gcc` command you show in the output ends with `-ldeezer`. So `make` is not using that `Makefile` or the contents of it are not what you showed or something similar has gone wrong. Maybe the `Makefile` is sitting in an editor buffer and you did not save it to the file system yet.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, my bad, I haven't saved the makefile on my last attempt but same output without and with `-lcurl` option

Comment: These things are *symbol versions* and they have nothing to do with the soname, so changing the soname will not help you,